# Instagram Followers Count Getting by API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am Creating a Scenrio in my application
A user enter his instagram username system will show his Name, Followers Count etc. by instagram API.
I have tried  Basic Display API for Instagram but this API is not addressing.

Comment: You can only get this with the Instagram Graph API, and that is limited to business/creator accounts to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follower count is not available using IG Basic Display API.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user

You can only receive follower count using Instagram Graph API, note that this only applies to IG Business or Creator Accounts
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user